# Autofac 2.2 and ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Areas support

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, autofac, asp.net-mvc-areas

In his blog Nicholas [announced support for ASP.NET MVC 2.0 Areas](http://nblumhardt.com/2010/05/autofac-2-2-released/). However, I couldn't get it working and from what I see in Autofac sourcecode, areas support is nowhere to be seen. More specifically, `RegisterControllers`

```
return builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(controllerAssemblies)
    .Where(t => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
        t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"));
```

does not mention areas anywhere, nor does `AutofacControllerFactory`.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that Areas continue to work in the same way as they would without the Autofac controller factory - just follow the usual setup for Areas and things should just work.